# How to select from two tables in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Can someone tell me how can I select from two tables? I have these tables.

The first is called: **Animals**

There is:

```
id   owner_name      animal_name
1    ludvik120       Larry
2    marekk50        Pat
3    ludvik120       Riki
```

The second is called: **Animal_food**

There is:

```
id   owner_name     food
1    marekk50       carrot
2    ludvik120      apple
3    ludvik120      orange
```

What i want achieve is output:

`Pat - carrot`,
`Larry - apple`,
`Riki - orange`

As you can see the columns "owner_name" are equal. Is it possible to do it like this or not ?

Comment: look at join statement

Comment: No you cannot as they are not unique. Because if you do a join you will also return `Larry - orange` and `Riki - apple`. Think all possible permutations

Comment: And some advice how can I do it ? Becouse i am new in it.

Comment: You should probably have a table linking the animal's food to the animal, and not the animal's owner. Otherwise there really is not a way to do so. Looking at the owner ludvik120, he has 2 pets, one eating apples and one eating oranges, and there is no data in the database allowing you to correctly link the food to the animal.

Comment: Thank you all for advices, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try this

   ```
   SELECT Animals.animal_name, Animal_food.food
   FROM Animals
   LEFT JOIN Animal_food
   ON Animals.owner_name=Animal_food.owner_name;
   ```
2. To concatenate both fields

   ```
   SELECT COALESCE(Animals.animal_name, ' - ') || COALESCE(Animal_food.food, ' - ') 
   FROM Animals
   LEFT JOIN Animal_food
   ON Animals.owner_name=Animal_food.owner_name;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.
SQL joins are used to combine rows from two or more tables.

Different types of JOINs:

1. (INNER) JOIN: Select records that have matching values in both tables.
2. LEFT (OUTER) JOIN: Select records from the first (left-most) table with matching right table records.
3. RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN: Select records from the second (right-most) table with matching left table records.
4. FULL (OUTER) JOIN: Selects all records that match either left or right table records.

General syntax is: SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name1 JOIN table-name2 
    ON column-name1 = column-name2
 WHERE condition

The programmer needs to figure out which one suits him/her according to his/her demands in the program.

Comment: And can you tell me what i need to use ? And how ? I am totally new in it

Answer (score 0):

```
I recomend to use Ids like this:
Animals 
AnimalId   owner_name      animal_name
1          ludvik120       Larry
2          marekk50        Pat
3          ludvik120       Riki

Animal_food
Animal_foodId   owner_name     food
1               marekk50       carrot
2               ludvik120      apple
3               ludvik120      orange

I think you need a third table to join and show the information as you need.
```

Relation

```
RelationId      AnimalId        Animal_foodId
1               2               1
2               1               2
3               3               3
```

And the query is:

```
Select A.animal_name, F.food
from Relation R
inner join Animals A on R.AnimalId = A.AnimalId
inner join Animal_food F on R.Animal_foodId = F.Animal_foodId
```

Good look.